# jQuery requesting my page a second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, httprequest

I'm not sure if I'm interpreting this correctly but it seems like Chrome is telling me jQuery is requesting my page a second time when it loads. When debugging my ASP.NET MVC partial view, I noticed it was being called twice. This lead me to look at the Network tab in Chrome developer tools and I see the page appear to load, and then a second request for the page is made and Chrome claims the initiator is this jQuery 1.12.0 line:

```
support.inlineBlockNeedsLayout = val = div.offsetWidth === 3;
```

Do you know why there is a 2nd request and how to stop it?

Comment: Is your server code hitting twice? if you place a debugger

Comment: Yes, the partial view is rendering twice on the server side.